# How to avoid double includes

Tags: c, include

I have an issue of an library that I want to include in all the files in my project.
My current structure is like this:

Lib1.h is included in Lib1.c

Lib2.h is included in Lib2.c

Lib1.c and Lib2.c is included in File1.c

File1.h is included in File1.c

I have a library I want to include in both Lib1.c and Lib2.c.
However if I do that then I get multiple includes of the same library in File1.
How do I get the functionality of the library in both Lib1 and Lib2 without causing errors with double includes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: @TerryTsao Somewhat, just not sure how to use it correctly. I cant add it to the library I want to include, as its external to the project, so it has to be in Lib1/lib2/File1. So im not sure how to go about it, but ill try some things out

Comment: Why not include File1.c, Lib1.c, and Lib2.c as separate sources in your project, instead of including Lib1.c and Lib2.c in File1.h?

Comment: Hmm, just looked into the library im trying to include, the header file does have include guard in it, so I dont know why i still get double include errors if thats the case

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yea, thats a mistake on my part, should have proofread my question better

Comment: That didn't make things better. You also should not include those .c files into `File1.c`. Only include headers and link together with the other .c files.

Comment: @Gerhardh Disagree with "Only include headers and link together with the other .c files.".  Although not common, there are select  times for a *.c to include *.c files.

Answer (score 4):

This is how the include guards are set in any header file (here in "Lib1.h")

```
#ifndef Lib1_h
#define Lib1_h

//your codes

#endif /* Lib1_h */
```